# Tfs build stuck in build queue

Tags: tfs

I accidentally deleted a build definition and did not realize that it was being used in the queue. When I try to cancel it an error shows: 404 Requested build 650 not found.

Is There a way to fix this without access to the server?

Comment: Is it only in the queue or currently being run by an agent?

Comment: @EvanOJack Sorry I didn't read your comment correctly. It is being run by the agent but there are no steps in the definition so its just idling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that you can navigate to the agent pool right click and select update. The Queue automatically canceled the stuck build after i did this.